# Как удалить программно приложение в Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть список объектов **ApplicationInfo**. Мне необходимо отобразить поочередно диалоговые окна, где пользователь может отказаться или удалить приложение со своего телефона.

```
val packageURI = Uri.parse("package:${it.packageName}")
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
startActivity(intent)
```

Данный код выводит как и нужно диалоговое окно, но без коллбека, где я могу узнать что выбрал пользователь, чтобы затем отобразить следующее диалоговое окно.

Также пытался удалить с помощью **PackageInstaller**, но ничего не удаляется и не отображается.

```
    val packageInstaller: PackageInstaller = context.packageManager.packageInstaller
        packageInstaller.uninstall(
            packageName,
            createUninstallIntentSender(context, packageName)
        )


    private fun createUninstallIntentSender(
        context: Context,
        packageName: String
    ): IntentSender {
        val intent = Intent(ACTION_UNINSTALL_COMPLETE)
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, packageName)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context, 0,
            intent, 0
        )
        return pendingIntent.intentSender
    }
```

Comment: Я в своем приложении просто запускал пакет Intent'ов и пользователь поочередно удаляет приложения или отказывается, ничего отслеживать не надо было.

Answer (score 1):

В настоящее время это не доступно для сторонних приложений. 
Использование рефлексии или других приемов доступа к install Package() не поможет, потому что его могут использовать только системные приложения. (Это связано с тем, что это механизм низкоуровневой установки после того, как разрешения дадим утверждены, поэтому для обычных приложений небезопасно иметь доступ к ним)